# How can I remove a false entry on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

How can I remove my entry from Facebook, which I have never joined but keep getting e mails addressed to me which are unsolicited? I believe someone has maliciously entered false details about me which is why I am getting the emails.

Answer (score 1):

Can you go to Facebook, and try to sign up with your email address, and then choose the Forgotten Password option?    This may get the password reset details emailed to you - in which case you can just log on, change the password to something you know, and delete all the content.